# detect/get notification if shift key (modifier-key) pressed in uitextview

Tags: uitextview, uikeyboard, shift, modifier-key

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way in which we can detect if <kbd>shift</kbd> key is pressed or if any notification is sent when <kbd>shift</kbd> key is pressed in `UIKeyboard`

```c
- (BOOL) textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)string
```

does not get called for <kbd>shift</kbd> key press since it is a modifier key.

Comment: This is possible now by overriding `pressesBegan`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73284986/15959847

Answer (score 2):

Don't know whether you need to know it in combination with other text or only detect the single shift tap, but here is my solution for detecting the former:

in my case this is only a single character within:

```c
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)inText
```

this converts uppercase text to lowercase and sets the shiftPressed Value (ignored if the text is non letter text)

```c
//Shift Detection
BOOL shiftPressed = NO;

//Detect non letter characters
NSCharacterSet *letterCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
NSString *trimmedText = [text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:letterCharacterSet];

if ([text length] == 1) {  
    if (![trimmedText length]) 
    {            
        NSString *upperCaseString = [text uppercaseString];
        if ([upperCaseString isEqualToString:text]) {
            NSString *lowerCaseString = [text lowercaseString];
            text = lowerCaseString;
            shiftPressed = YES;
        }
    }
}
```